# tkinter Canvas window not opening from Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, canvas, tkinter

When running on Win10 the following script against the Python 3.8.2 command line, it works just fine, opens a Tk window and displays a triangle:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 60, 50, 35)
```

However, when running the same script from the PowerShell command line with

```
& "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python38-32/python.exe" c:/Users/Me/sample.py
```

The script terminates without error and without opening the Tk window.

How can I get the Tk window to open while calling the Python interpreter from PowerShell command line?

Comment: What is the value of `$LASTEXITCODE` immediately after invoking `python`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you forgot to add

```
tk.mainloop()
```

at the end of your script which keeps the window running.

Let me know if adding this fixes your problem.